# Add custom element ID depending where the widget place is, sidebar or footer

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, sidebar

I'm creating a custom widget and I want to return a different element ID. The ID would be something like, `instafeed-sidebar` and `instafeed-footer`. This is depending where the widget added.

Register sidebars:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Post Sidebar', 'nubia' ),
    'id'            => 'post-sidebar',
    'description'   => esc_html__( '', 'nubia' ),
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="c-widget c-widget--sidebar %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<h5 class="c-widget--sidebar__title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h5>',
  ) );

  register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer First', 'nubia' ),
    'id'            => 'footer-first',
    'description'   => esc_html__( '', 'nubia' ),
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="c-widget c-widget--footer %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<h5 class="c-widget--footer__title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h5>',
  ) );
```

Widget code:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  extract($args);

  // ...

  <div id='instafeed' class='c-widget-instagram'></div>

  <?php

  echo $after_widget;
}
```

I don't want to use the widget dynamic ID, but rather an ID that I choose.

So if the widget added to the registered sidebar, the element would be:

```
<div id='instafeed-sidebar' class='c-widget-instagram'></div>
```

If the widget added to the footer, the element would be:

```
<div id='instafeed-footer' class='c-widget-instagram'></div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: in the method `widget` you can read the sidebar identifier in `$args["id"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by following the advice from @mmm. Using `$args["id"]` did the trick.

Using `$args["id"]` will return the following:

`post-sidebar`

`footer-first`

With a little change, my final code is:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  extract($args);

  // ...

  <div id='instafeed-<?php echo explode("-", $args["id"])[0] ;?>' class='c-widget-instagram'></div>

  <?php

  echo $after_widget;
}
```

The result is:

```
<div id='instafeed-post' class='c-widget-instagram'></div>
<div id='instafeed-footer' class='c-widget-instagram'></div>
```

Thanks